# Count cells based on multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

On my sheet named "*Peer Company Summary*", I'd like to count the number cells with the value of 1 on my sheet named "*Raw Data*"  on Column D, with respect to it matching the company name on "*Peer Company Summary*" on Column A to match Column A on "*Raw Data*" as well.

How would I count the total number as well? Some values on Column D on "*Raw Data*" have the values 1, 2, or 3 and I'd like to count all that with respect to the company name.

What formula would I use? This is MS Excel 2010.

[image: Peer Company Summary Sheet]

[image: Raw Data]

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS.  Put this in D2 and copy over and down

```
=COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!$A:$A,$A2,'Raw Data'!$D:$D,COLUMN(A:A))
```

Comment: Seems like it would only give me total and it isn't working right. I'm looking for it to count the cells that have the value "1", value "2", and total.

Comment: That is what the `COLUMN(A:A)` does.  it returns `1` in D2, then when copied over it turns to `COLUMN(B:B)` which is `2` and so on.  so it will count where ever the row names match AND column D on Raw Data is `1`.

Comment: Then in the third column you would put a sum formula: `=D2+E2`

Comment: Not quite. So for Acorda, it counted the total number, which is 6. I'm looking to only count the total number with the value 1. On my raw data sheet, there is the value 2. 

Here are my results:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TnUcCC_WkAx7_zJ0DZ8D-12cs8CAjgHD/view?usp=sharing

What I'm seeing: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JnDrQLt5oVNDVJvcru5_ZvpxIFom1uXU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are 6 that have `1` not `5` the formula returned the correct amount. ROWS 2,3,4,5,6,7 all have `1` and are `Acorda` that is `6`

Comment: And if it looks like it doubled check the data all the way down the list, the data may be doubled in your Raw Data sheet.

Comment: And I do not download items from the internet, from people I hardly know.  It is not that I do not trust you personally, it is just a rule of mine.  I have been burned too many times.